# AppGyver and AngularJS: dependency injection failing with 2 services from same module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, appgyver

Im failing at using two angularJS services from the same module in my controller.

Im using AngularJS in my AppGyver application (MPA oriented).

I have the following architecture:

```
- common/services/
            - ServiceCampaign.js
            - ServiceUser.js
- home/scripts/
            - HomeController.js
- home/
            - index.js
```

**ServiceCampaign.js**

```
angular
    .module( 'services', [] )
    .service( 'serviceCampaign', function( $http ) {

      this.getStuff = function(){ return "from service campaign"; };

});
```

**ServiceUser.js**

```
angular
    .module( 'services', [] )
    .service( 'serviceUser', function( $http ) {

     this.getStuff = function(){ return "from service user"; };

});
```

**HomeController.js**

```
angular
  .module( 'home' )
  .controller( 'HomeController', function($scope, supersonic, serviceUser, serviceCampaign) {

    var campaignStuff = serviceCampaign.getStuff();
    var userStuff = serviceUser.getStuff();

});
```

**index.js** (used for dependency injection)

```
angular.module('home', [
  // Declare any module-specific AngularJS dependencies here
  'common', 'services'
]);
```

This is obviously failing with this nice error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: serviceUserProvider <- serviceUser <- HomeController
```

(Its working if I only put one dependency to my "services" module in HomeController.js)

Is there an easy way to get this working? What is the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change your home controller to look like this: `.module( 'home' , [])`

Comment: you mean by editing the index.js file related to my home controller or the HomeController.js file itself?

Comment: The HomeController.js file itself.

Answer (score 0):

in your index.js initialize 'services' before

```
angular.module('services', []);

angular.module('home', [
  // Declare any module-specific AngularJS dependencies here
  'common', 'services'
]);
```

and than you can do all that 'services' without square brackets

```
angular
    .module( 'services')
    .service( 'serviceCampaign', function( $http ) {
      this.getStuff = function(){ return "from service campaign"; };
});


angular
    .module( 'services')
    .service( 'serviceUser', function( $http ) {

     this.getStuff = function(){ return "from service user"; };

});
```

Comment: create fiddle, and I can look at that